# XSLT: Using following-sibling on an array of strings?

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Having tokenized an attribute containing a file path (e.g. /dir1/dir2/dir3), I now have an array (or node set?) of strings.

I would like to recursively process the first item and pass the rest on - and had hoped to accomplish this using the 'following-sibling' axis. However, it turns out that it expects actual elements and not merely strings.

```
<xsl:template match="s:universe">
    <xsl:call-template name="createSubFolder">
        <xsl:with-param name="folderNames" select="tokenize(@path, '/')" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="createSubFolder">
    <xsl:param name="folderNames" />
    <xsl:if test="count($folderNames) > 0">
        <folder>
            <xsl:attribute name="name" select="$folderNames[1]" />
            <xsl:if test="position() &lt; count($folderNames)">
                <folder>
                    <xsl:call-template name="createSubFolder">
                        <xsl:with-param name="folderNames" select="$folderNames[1]/following-sibling::text()" />
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </folder>
            </xsl:if>
        </folder>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

The only solution I currently imagine would be creating a custom function which feeds the tail end of an array to the template - but I have the feeling that there could/must be a better way.

Comment: With `tokenize(@path, '/')` you get a sequence of strings and if you want to process it recursively then you are right to use the tail with (XPath 3) `tail($folderNames)` or `$folderNames[position() gt 1]` (XPath 2).

Comment: @MartinHonnen: Did not realize tail() existed. Will give that a go!

Comment: You might want to bookmark http://maxtoroq.github.io/xpath-ref/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Martin Honnen mentioned in the comments, `tokenize(@path, '/')` returns sequence of string(s). So you cannot use `following-sibling` axis to the string type.

You can use `subsequence($folderNames,2)` or `$folderNames[position() gt 1]` to use recursive call like following:

```
<xsl:template name="createSubFolder">
    <xsl:param name="folderNames" as="xs:string*"/>
    <xsl:if test="exists(($folderNames[1]))">
        <folder>
            <xsl:attribute name="name" select="$folderNames[1]" />
            <xsl:call-template name="createSubFolder">
                <xsl:with-param name="folderNames" select="subsequence($folderNames,2)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </folder>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Using subsequence() - very nice. I was Googling for 'arrays' when I should have been Googling for 'sequences'!